# Why do weird edge lines appear connecting vertices that are not corrected the same way in Blender show up after render?

Tags: modeling

I am extremely new to blender, and have a very basic idea how to use the tools to create models for games I would like to make. I am in the middle of making a simple pizza slice, and all went well during the creation, but when I exported to a .FBX file, the resulting model had weird glitch-looking lines where the "mushrooms" on the pizza slice are. I hope that someone out there more knowledgeable than me can explain the issue to me so I know for the future, as I have only watched two tutorials to learn the complete basics. Thank you!

Here are the images while in blender:
[image: Blender image wire frame]
[image: Blender image solid angle view]

Here are the images in Microsoft's 3d viewer (it's kind of hard to see as I texture the models when I get into the game engine):
[image: Image in 3dviewer]
[image]

P.S. I only screenshotted one of the mushrooms on the slice, but both are having the same issue that I tried to describe.

Comment: most likely you are dealing with non planar, and or overlapping faces.

Comment: @susu I was able to fix it by doing research on the topics you gave and found that triangulating the objects fixed it by adding more geometry. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by doing research on the topics you gave and found that triangulating the objects fixed it by adding more geometry. The steps were to select the object/mesh, go to edit mode, and press CTRL+T.